# VSCode debugger messing up relative paths

Tags: javascript, debugging, npm, visual-studio-code

So I'm trying to run the VSCode debugger run my express program, but I noticed that it's messing up the relative directory paths.

When using a module like `JIMP`, a Node image manipulator, when I run the app from the Powershell, I need to enter the path relative to the project root (where the `package.JSON` is) to find the image. But when I run it from the VSCode debugger, I get an error, because it is finding the image relative to my `app` directory, which is a folder in my project root.

Is there a configuration I can edit to fix this?

`launch.json` :

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible Node.js debug attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "npm start",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app/app.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

`jsconfig.js` :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Solved it:

You need to include `"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"` in your `launch.json`

Comment: "The variable ${workspaceRoot} was deprecated in favor of ${workspaceFolder} to better align with Multi-root Workspace support." - [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_why-isnt-workspaceroot-documented)